# Возможно ли передать аргументы из функции с переменным числом параметров в другую вункцию с переменным числом параметров?

Tags: c++, c

Возможно ли передать аргументы из функции с переменным числом параметров в другую вункцию с переменным числом параметров в си стиле(без шаблонов)?

```
void exemple_format(const char* str, ...)
{
  prontf(str, /* как сюда передать переменные параметры из вызывающей функции? /*)
}
```

Comment: Есть `vprintf`, посмотрите на нее, как раз для этого случая :)

Comment: Коль скоро это C++, луше все же воспользоваться шаблоном с переменным числом параметров

Comment: Это невозможно. Можно передать только `va_list`.